# cocoa stopModal to close the Modal Window but do not give focus to previous application

Tags: macos, cocoa, modal-dialog, focus

I write a npapi plugin for Safari, and I write a framework to show a modal window dialog to get password . Safari invoke plugin and plugin invoke framework. everything works well but when I close the dialog , Safari do not get the focus , I must click on the html to active safari , so it get the focus .

I show the modal dialog with following code:

```
NSModalSession session = [NSApp beginModalSessionForWindow:[self window]];
for (;;)
{
    if ([NSApp runModalSession:session] != NSModalResponseContinue)
        break;
}
[NSApp endModalSession:session];
```

and close the modal window with:

```
[self stopModal];
```

But if I show the modal window with:

```
[NSApp runModalForWindow:[self window]];
```

it works well .

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Showing modal dialogs (in fact, opening windows in general) is not a supported part of NPAPI, and is strongly discouraged. The problem is that you are doing something that NPAPI isn't designed to do, and that interacts poorly with out-of-process plugin hosting.

Comment: may be you are right smorgan ,but I found a solution, in my framework, when I close the modal window . I make the Safari active,so it get focued.

Comment: Your question was why it was broken, not whether there was a workaround, which is why my answer is what it is.